# Failed to create service linked role: AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup due to missing permissions for 'iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I created EKS cluster in AWS and i want to create Node group (worker nodes) for corresponding created cluster but getting error "Failed to create service linked role: AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup due to missing permissions for 'iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole". Pls help.

I'm following the instructions present in AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html)

Comment: The user you are logging into the AWS console as does not have permission to perform the action that you are attempting. If you are not the account owner, contact them about the permissions you need.

Comment: Thank you @jordanm. Like you mentioned, i does not have permission to perform the action. Created eks cluster and worker nodes through eksctl command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to `eksctl` documentation page: https://eksctl.io/usage/minimum-iam-policies/

That page shows all policies that need to be assigned to a AWS user in order to manage a kubernetes cluster in AWS, but **read my entire answer before continuing**.

**IMPORTANT**

Create `EksAllAccess` and `IamLimitedAccess` remembering to replace `<account_id>` with your AWS account id.

Policies named `AmazonEC2FullAccess` and `AWSCloudFormationFullAccess` already exist in AWS. **DO NOT USE** the built-in policies. Create your own (you can use the same name).

The `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy differs a little bit from the built-in version. Moreover, the version on the above-mentioned page is still missing one entry: `"eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com",`.

The last part of the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy definition should go like this:

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                "ec2scheduled.amazonaws.com",
                "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                "eks.amazonaws.com",
                "eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com",
                "eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com",
                "spot.amazonaws.com",
                "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
                "transitgateway.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to AWS documentation for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/using-service-linked-roles-eks-nodegroups.html