# IAM Roles for EC2 when creating EKS Cluster using eksctl

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli, amazon-eks, eksctl

Which IAM role/roles should I assign to an EC2 Instance to create EKS Cluster using eksctl command line tool? As storing AWS CLI credentials in EC2 Instance is not a secure option.

Comment: Please check my answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005105/1053510

Comment: Why it is not advisable to use built-in policies?

Comment: I explained it in the answer above. There's a built-in policy called `AmazonEC2FullAccess` but it is missing some entry and won't work with `eksctl`. I spent a whole day until I figured that out ;)